# NavigableString' object has no attribute 'contents'

Tags: python, iot

I'm getting an error
"NavigableString' object has no attribute 'contents'"
I got the code from hackster.io
https://www.hackster.io/amir-pournasserian/covid-19-iot-dashboard-w-raspberry-pi-ccc77f
I am trying to replicate the project given above but I'm not able to code it properly cuz I recently started to learn python.There are some other code files in the website I linked above that I used like main.py,world_case_collector,etc.

I hope you guys can help me!

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bf
import requests
import _const_cases as const

num_places = 220 #number of countries

def getting_world_value(today): #getting the value from website
    data_list = []
    html = requests.get("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus")
    soup = bf(html.text,'html.parser')
    if today:
        tag = soup("tr")[9:9 + num_places]
    else:
        tag = soup("tr")[239:239 + num_places]

    def extract_vals(arr):
        temp_list = []
        arr_size = len(arr) - 2
        for j in range(arr_size):
            if j == 1:
                temp_list.append(arr.contents[j].contents[0].contents[0])
            elif j % 2 == 1:
                value = arr.contents[j].contents
                if len(value) == 0:
                    value.append('0')
                value = value[0]
                value = value.replace("\n", "")
                value = value.replace("+", "")
                value = value.replace(",", "")
                value = value.replace("N/A", "")
                if len(value) == 0 or value == ' ':
                    value = '0'
                temp_list.append(value)
        return temp_list  
          
    compare_list = extract_vals(tag[-1])

    for i in range(len(tag)):        
        insert_list = extract_vals(tag[i])

        def continents(arg, day):
            if day:
                switcher = { 
                    212: 'North America', 
                    213: 'Europe', 
                    214: 'Asia',  
                    215: 'South America', 
                    216: 'Oceania', 
                    217: 'Africa', 
                    218: 'Unknown',
                    219: 'World',
                } 
            else:
                switcher = { 
                    211: 'Asia', 
                    212: 'North America', 
                    213: 'Europe',  
                    214: 'South America', 
                    215: 'Oceania', 
                    216: 'Africa', 
                    217: 'Unknown',
                    218: 'World'
                }
            return switcher.get(arg, insert_list[const.country])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be better for you to provide the whole error message and format it into the post appropriately. Also, please, consider this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This community is not used to debug code